# Getting "SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to use `document.write` in order to create a html element that will link to a function. However I am getting:

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"
```

The `document.write` is also inside a for loop as it needs to dynamically create links for each piece of data.

```
standardArray[i] = '<a href ="javascript:void(0);" onclick = "showDetails(null, null, ' + stdata.rows.item(i).Title + ');">' + stdata.rows.item(i).StandardNumber + ' ' + stdata.rows.item(i).Title;
document.write(standardArray[i]);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `CORNEAL CALCIUM CHELATION` is not a proper JavaScript syntax.

Comment: thats what the value becomes once its stored into the array

Comment: Try this `standardArray[i] = "<a href ='javascript:void(0);' onclick = 'showDetails(null, null, '" + stdata.rows.item(i).Title + "')';>" + stdata.rows.item(i).StandardNumber + " "+ stdata.rows.item(i).Title;
`

Answer (score 1):

I assume CORNEAL CALCIUM CHELATION is a string, so you need to format your onclick as follows:

`showDetails(null, null, 'CORNEAL CALCIUM CHELATION');`

Comment: Could you view my edited code and show how I would be able to make that element a string?

Comment: Just put single quotes between inserted string `(...)"showDetails(null, null, \'' + stdata.rows.item(i).Title + '\');"`. Look at `\'` at the end of string before title variable and at the start of string after it